# Asciidoctor: Wrong Encoding in the Footer

Tags: encoding, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I saved my .adoc file as UTF-8 and compiled it with asciidoctor (on Windows 10). In the text I wrote, there are no encoding problems, but in the automatically generated footer I get

```
Last updated 2016-08-27 11:52:56 Mitteleuropõische Sommerzeit
```

You see that I compiled on a German machine. For those not too familiar with German, the "õ" should be an "ä" instead.

I guess there is some problem in generating the timestamp. I would like to either correct the misspelling or change the time format so that it does not contain "words". Can anybody help?

Comment: It seems that [the time format of Asciidoctor is hardcoded to be `%H:%M:%S %Z`](//github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/cad9b76245f71ba6bab9657dea8568f97cb3d001/lib/asciidoctor/document.rb#L406), where `%Z` is the "wordy" timezone indicator. Note that this timestamp is [only written in under certain conditions](//github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/0e5af28bba0d7df9fa84840b3559f2bd249e5a0b/lib/asciidoctor/converter/html5.rb#L197); maybe it's easier to disable the footer altogether, or tell Asciidoctor to make "reproducible" documents.

Comment: Also, the encoding of the German name for CEST on Windows is [known to be a problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/jO0RO7AJ8SU); what `%Z` does is locale- and platform-dependent, and in this case it's German (because of the locale) and ISO-8859-1 (because of Windows' C standard library).

Comment: Not only German, problem with all accented letters. In French, I get `Last updated 2018-04-13 06:36:55 Paris, Madrid (heure dÆÚtÚ)` (the last should be `heure d'été`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Asciidoctor 1.5.8, see: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/2770

We are not using `%Z` anymore because `%Z` is OS dependent and may contain characters that aren't UTF-8 encoded: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/cb7c20593344bda9bc968a619b02065d3401ad29/lib/asciidoctor/document.rb#L1253-L1254